# Expanding div vertically to fit parent container

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create the following layout using CSS:

[image: Desired Layout]

- Gray Rectangle = Container
- Blue Rectangle = Image
- White Rectangle = Content

Unfortunately the best I've been able to manage is this:

[image: Achieved Layout]

I have two problems with the content div:

1. How to make the content div sit to the right of the image without hard coding the width.
2. How to make the content div expand vertically to fill the container.

Apologies if a similar question has already been asked.  I've read similar questions here but they all seem to relate to other layout concerns.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="solid">
      <img id="snapshot" src="page.jpg">
      <div class="content" style="margin-left: 165px;">
        Test
      </div>
      <br style="clear:both"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#snapshot {
  float: left;
}

div.solid {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #E8E8FF;
}

div.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Do you at least know the width of the image?

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to avoid this but in this case using fixed width images will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the width of the image, you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EeLjd/

Use `position: absolute` on the content, and set the `left` to the width of the image, plus the padding. Use `float: left` on the image.

Answer (score 3):

Equal height columns are always a pain. If the image width is fixed, perhaps the easiest way is to put the image *inside* the content div and then push it back to the left with a negative margin:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="solid">
      <div class="content" style="margin-left: 165px">
      <img id="snapshot" src="page.jpg" style="margin-left: -165px;">
        Test
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this works!  Unfortunately I can only accept one answer and I'm using minitech's solution. Conceptually I find the structure of the HTML more closely matches the actual layout on the page.